# How to get solid box-shadow on all sides only using CSS3?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make something similar to the button showed in picture.

[image]

I tried the following:

```css
.button {
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    background: qlineargradient(to bottom, #ededed 5%, #dfdfdf 100%);
    background-color:#ededed;
    border-radius:6px;
    border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:red;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:6px 24px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #ffffff;
}
```

The above CSS3 code gave me the following:

[image]

I am not sure how to make the same button with a border that looks similar to the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all the 4 parts of the box shadow are x offset y offset and blur and the spread I did some tweaks to your code and got this output.

```css
.button {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px 2px #000;
  background: qlineargradient(to bottom, #ededed 5%, #dfdfdf 100%);
  background-color: #ededed;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: red;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 6px 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>`substitute(Filename('', 'Page Title'), '^.', '\u&', '')`</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="button">
    quit
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no CSS property called `qlineargradient` so it's been removed. The `box-shadow` property in the example below has 3 values which makes layers top to bottom.

```css
button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 24px;
  border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  border-radius: 6px;
  color: red;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #fff;  
  box-shadow: 
  rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25) 0px 5px 8px -2px,
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 3px 6px -3px, 
  rgba(10, 37, 64, 0.35) 0px -2px 6px 0px inset;
  background-color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  box-shadow: 
  rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.55) 0px 5px 8px -2px,
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 3px 6px -3px, 
  rgba(10, 37, 64, 0.35) 0px -2px 6px 0px inset;
}
```

```html
<button>QUIT</button>
```